# Pandas: Pivoting and plotting workflow

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

Disclaimer: I am very new to Pandas.

I am doing numerical simulations and would like to use Pandas for the final data-evaluation. To keep things simple let's assume the following setup:

My simulations take a few input parameters (E.g. `max`, and `size`). The simulation then produces a number of observables as functions of time (E.g. `f1(t)`, `f2(t)`). In the end, the results of three different simulations could look like this:

```
t1 = np.linspace(0, 2, 15)
t2 = np.linspace(0, 2, 21)
t3 = np.linspace(0, 1.5, 16)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'max': t1.max(), 'size': t1.size, 't': t1, 'f1': t1**2+0, 'f2': t1**3+0})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'max': t2.max(), 'size': t2.size, 't': t2, 'f1': t2**2+1, 'f2': t2**3+1})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'max': t3.max(), 'size': t3.size, 't': t3, 'f1': t3**2+2, 'f2': t3**3+2})
```

Where `max`, and `size` are the parameters to each simulation, `t` is the time axis, and `f1`, and `f2` are the observables.

---

Say, as a first task, I would like to plot the values of `f1` as a function of `t` for each set of parameters. After spending some time with the docs I found that the `pivot_table` function can rearrange my data in the right way.

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])
df_ms = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['t'], values=['f1', 'f2'], columns=['max', 'size'])
```

**Intermediate question**: Is this the best way to do this? I know that `DataFrame` takes an `index` argument in its constructor. Would it be better to define `t` as the index at that point? (I couldn't get it working together with `pivot_table`)

---

Now we can use the `plot` method to plot the resulting data.

```
df_ms['f1'].plot()
```

The result, however, is unexpected. I understand that some data is missing, as pandas is forced to introduce NaNs when aligning the different `t` axes.

**My question**:
Why doesn't the green curve show up at all? And why are the blue and red patches aligned? Is there a simple way to skip the NaNs in the plot, along the lines of what you would get by simply calling `plt.plot(t, f1)` in matplotlib?

[image: Plot with missing data]

I know that it is possible to fill the NaNs by interpolation. For the given case second order splines are quite ideal.

```
df_ms['f1'].interpolate(method='spline', order=2).plot()
```

However, I am wondering why this should be necessary for simply plotting the data. Matplotlib's internal linear interpolation would be sufficient...

[image: Plot with interpolation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `nan`s behave logically, but not always very intuitively.

If you plot a continuous line, a `nan` will naturally remove line segments from both sides of the `nan` point. So, if your data (green line) never has two numbers as adjacent elements, it will not be drawn. For example, if `f1` is then `[nan, 1, nan, 1.2, nan, nan, 2.3]`, no segments can be drawn.

**Fix #1**: draw points instead of lines (`plot(t, f1, 'o')`), then you'll at least see all your data.

**Fix #2**: remove all `nan`s from your data before plotting. Let us assume `t` has all values but `f1` is missing values:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

nonnans = -np.isnan(f1)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(t[nonnans], f1[nonnans])
```

So, just create an array telling which of the samples are good, and use only those samples in plotting. (And in case you are wondering, the `ax.plot` stuff is equivalent to `plt.plot` but using the recommended object-oriented interface.)

The way `plot` treats `nan`s may feel a bit annoying at first, but it is very useful once you grasp it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You see, my issue is that the NaNs are only introduced by pandas in the first place. In my original data I don't have any NaNs. They appear when I'm pivoting my data. Now, I completely understand why pandas introduces NaNs to align the data. However, do you know of an easy way to make pandas skip them when plotting? The fix you describe would work, of course, but then I could skip pandas all-together and directly plot the results of my individual simulations. Maybe `pivot_table` is the wrong function for what I want to achieve. Can you comment on that?

Comment: I think the interpolation is actually the right thing to do if you need to have the data in common time grid. You essentially have points in time without the data. Then you'll just have to guess the data, and interpolation is one way of doing that. I am not a pandas expert, but your pivot does not look bad. If the measurement results had different names for different runs (e.g. `f1_1`, `f1_2`), you could use `concat([df1,df2,df3]).sort('t')`, but still you'd have the `NaN`s there.

Answer (score 1):

The validate values in the `(2.0,21)` column is to few, in factor there are no 2 consecutive validate values in that column. Two point are required to define a line, therefore we don't see any lines be drawn for that column, it can be easily see when we plot the `df.fillna(0)`:

```
df_ms['f1'].plot()
plt.figure()
df_ms['f1'].fillna(0).plot()
```

[image]
[image]

The same applies to the other columns as can be seen from the comparisons of the above two plots.

Comment: Thanks, with that second plot it becomes much clearer what's going on.